# Android custom listView application kept on crashing without showing anything

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to build a custom `listView` (layout contain only 3 `textViews`).
Below is my code, i am only extending `ArrayAdapter<String>` and filling up with my own constructor but at the time of execution, application kept on crashing without showing anyting.

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
// ... more imports

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Resources res = getResources( );
    String[] days = res.getStringArray(R.array.days);
    String[] title = res.getStringArray(R.array.title);
    String[] desc = res.getStringArray(R.array.desc);

    ListView lv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

        customArrayAdapter adp = new customArrayAdapter(this, days, title, desc);

        lv.setAdapter(adp);
    }
}

class customArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    String[] title;
    String[] desc;

    customArrayAdapter(Context c, String[] name, String[] title, String[] desc) {
        super(c, R.layout.single_row, R.id.tv1, name);

        this.context = c;
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inf.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);

        TextView tv1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        TextView tv3 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv3);

        tv2.setText(title[position]);
        tv3.setText(desc[position]);

        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a logcat of the error you are getting.

Comment: getResources( ) defind oncreate method prb solve

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
com.customlistview.rameez.custom_listview, PID: 8001
                                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.customlistview.rameez.custom_listview/com.customlistview.rameez.custom_listview.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Resources res;
    //stuff

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        res = getResources();

        //stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        Context context;
        ListView lv;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            context = getApplicationContext();

            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

            customArrayAdapter adp = new customArrayAdapter(context, days, title, desc);

            lv.setAdapter(adp);
        }
```

Comment: It may help you reslove the crashing  problem